# SQL Queries: How to select required data from 2 tables given a calculation criteria?

Tags: sql

Given the following situation.

- Table 1: `House`
- Columns: House_name, House_info, House_latitude, House_longitude
- Table 2: `Stop`
- Columns: Stop_name, Stop_latitude, Stop_longitude

Distance between house and stop (formula):

[DISTANCE FORMULA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUyrz.png)

If I want to know their distance between all houses and stops (below 0.006),
how can I select house_name, house_info, stop_name, stop_info and distance.

My attempt:

```
SELECT 
    house_name, house_info, stop_name, stop_info, 
    SQRT(POWER(house_latitude - stop_latitude, 2) + POWER(house_longitude - stop_longitude, 2)) AS Distance
FROM 
    House, Stop
WHERE 
    SQRT(POWER(house_latitude - stop_latitude, 2) + POWER(house_longitude - stop_longitude, 2)) < 0.006
```

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuniZ.png)

Comment: How do you know which stops correspond to which houses? How are you linking stops and houses?

Comment: And except that it's a cross join, which is probably expensive for performances (but if you ain't any relationship between your tables, I don't see how to do it another way), what's wrong with your query ?

Comment: i would like to know the distance between all houses and all stops.   Suppose house A -> Stop B, HOUSE A -> STOP B, HOUSE A -> STOP C

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: what RDBMS you using?